# Minimize smooth function $(x,y) \to f(x,y)$ subject to $x \perp y$

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-optimization, orthogonal-matrices, paper-request, non-convex-optimization

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space (e.g space of $m \times n$ real matrices equiped with Hilbert-Schmidt inner product $(A,B) \to \mathrm{tr}(AB^\top)$, and let $f:V^2 \to \mathbb R$, $(x,y) \to f(x,y)$ be a continuously-differentiable function (say with Lipschitz-continuous gradient, if that helps).

> What is a principled strategy to go about minimizing $f$ on $V^2$ subject to the constraint $x \perp y$ ?

Of course, one could try do something like

- Do gradient descent on $x$ and $y$.
- Project $y$ on the orthogonal complement of $x$.

I don't how rigorous this is or of whether it even converges.

Comment: I guess, projecting onto the set $\{(x,y)\mid x\bot y\}$ should be doable, so you could to projected gradient descent, if you want to. But how about solving the problem with by standard Lagrange multipliers? Depending on $f$, this might work directly.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the input. This is reassuring because The stuff I wrote above is pretty much projected gradient descent on the set $\{(x,y) \mid x \perp y = 0\}$. Do you have a ref for (even local) convergence of projected gradient descent ? Also, I'd rather not do lagrangian methods, because I want the constraint to be satisfied exactly.

Comment: "projected gradient descent non-convex" brings up several recent references. And with "Lagrange multipliers" I meant the standard approach to formulate optimality systems for constraint optimization problems. This is used to solve problems exactly. What you have in mind seems to be penalization approaches.